# Django direct_to_template with wildcard in version 1.5

Tags: django

I've been using this catchall in my urls.py but of course it won't work in django 1.5.  Can I go direct to a template without knowing it's name in django 1.5?

```
# go straight to any urls ending in .html
(r'(.+\.html)$', 'django.views.generic.simple.direct_to_template'),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this purpose you can use the `render` shortcut which has a equivalent signature to the deprecated `direct_to_template`.

```
# go straight to any urls ending in .html
(r'(.+\.html)$', 'django.shortcuts.render'),
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#render